# Forcing v-validate to update rules (with Vue)

Tags: javascript, arrays, validation, vue.js, rules

I'm using v-validate with Vue. I'm trying to figure out how to force v-validate to update rules. For example, I have something like this:

```
<template>
  <div v-for="field in fields">
    <input :name="field.name" v-validate="field.rules">
  </div>
</template>
<script>
  export default {
    data() {
      fields: [
        {
          name: "city",
          rules: {
            included: []
          }
        }
      ]
    }
  }
</script>
```

As you can see, my "included" array is empty on page load. I get the array from an AJAX request, and then I update my data:

```
this.fields[0].rules.included = cities
```

But v-validate doesn't seem to acknowledge the newly-added array. It only works if I hardcode the cities into my data. How can I force v-validate to respond to the updated rules?

Answer (score 0):

Vue.js is unable to track updates on nested reference types.

Try:

```
let fields = [...this.fields]
fields[0].rules = cities
this.fields = fields
```

Answer (score 0):

Use Vue.set to track changes : https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/reactivity.html

```
Vue.set(this.fields[0], 'rules', cities);
```